# How does JavaMail API expunge messages when IMAP folder is closed

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail

I wonder, how JavaMail API expunges IMAP messages when [Folder.close(true)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#close(boolean)) is being called? According to the docs, the only parameter "expunge" of method "close" determines whether to expunge all messages that have been previously marked with a \Deleted flag. In the [source code (V. 1.4.7)](https://java.net/projects/javamail/downloads/download/source/javamail-1.4.7-src.zip), however, I cannot see any piece of code in the method close (class IMAPFolder), that expunges anything or does anything even going into that direction. Can anyone help me understand the effect of the expunge parameter?

Thank you very much in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: you linked to `org.apache.geronimo.javamail` sourcedoc and provided bytecode from `javax.mail`. These are two completely different things. Which will it be?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the docs link. It's javax.mail package.

Comment: CLOSE is defined by IMAP to do an expunge.

Comment: Yes, but even if the expunge parameter is set to false, a CLOSE operation is also sent to the IMAP server, if the server does not have the "UNSELECT" capability. That "expunge" parameter is extremely misleading paramter name, if it just determines to either send a CLOSE operation or just unselect the mailbox.

Comment: Looks like it's a best effort: try to close without expunging (using unselect).

Comment: no, if the expunge parameter is set to `false` no `CLOSE` command will be sent : http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.mail/mail/1.4.7/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.java#IMAPFolder.close%28boolean%2Cboolean%29

Comment: According to the code, it may also be sent when expunge is false and we're in READ_WRITE mode and the server does not have the "UNSELECT" capability.

Comment: However, I get the point. The expunge paramter is based around closing the mailbox. EXPUNGE, however, is a special IMAP command wich may be called explicitely. It is therefore misleading to name this parameter exactly the same.

Comment: @xSNRG heres the trick : `examine` apparently re-opens the folder read-only hence even a `CLOSE` will not expunge, this is explained in the the javadoc of the newest version : https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.java?rev=713

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMAPFolder.class, line 1310 :

```
 // If the expunge flag is set, close the folder first.
 if (expunge && protocol != null)
    protocol.close();
```

IMAPProtocol.class, line 1201 :

```
 /**
 * CLOSE Command.
 *
 * @see "RFC2060, section 6.4.2"
 */
public void close() throws ProtocolException {
   simpleCommand("CLOSE", null);
}
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2060#section-6.4.2 :

> The CLOSE command permanently removes from the currently selected
> mailbox all messages that have the \Deleted flag set, and returns to
> authenticated state from selected state.  No untagged EXPUNGE
> responses are sent.
>
> No messages are removed, and no error is given, if the mailbox is
> selected by an EXAMINE command or is otherwise selected read-only.
>
> Even if a mailbox is selected, a SELECT, EXAMINE, or LOGOUT command
> MAY be issued without previously issuing a CLOSE command. The SELECT,
> EXAMINE, and LOGOUT commands implicitly close the currently selected
> mailbox without doing an expunge.  However, when many messages are
> deleted, a CLOSE-LOGOUT or CLOSE-SELECT

Comment: Line 1310 is only executed when the connection pool is full (your first piece of code).

Comment: no, there is a second `else` below that condition - in which the the parameter is chedked again. I dont think you actually wanted to know about it, you obviously just want to criticize a working implementation. `CLOSE` only happens if the expunge paremeter is set, end of story. If you want to forward your thoughts to the package developers you're free to do so.

Comment: However, I get the point. The expunge paramter is based around closing the mailbox. EXPUNGE, however, is a special IMAP command wich may be called explicitely. It is therefore misleading to name this parameter exactly the same.

Comment: The effect on the mailbox is the same as if you used the EXPUNGE command - the deleted messages are permanently removed.  BTW, note that the [current version of JavaMail is 1.5.3](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: no, it is not exactly the same - see my last comment in his question.